# React Native App adb is out of date, how can we update it?

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I installed `create-react-native-app` using `yarn`.

`yarn create-react-native-app`

Now, I have created my application named - `myFirstProj` as below -

`create-react-native-app myFirstProj`

I have installed Genymotion Android emulator and pointed to the up-to-date Android SDK. It has `adb version 1.0.39`

I can launch the emulator successfully, but I am not able to view my app on Android emulator, i get this error -

`could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon`

So, i checked the adb version in the node_modules of my app -

*Path*: `node_modules/xdl/binaries/osx/adb`

I see that the adb version is `1.0.32`

Is there a way I can update my adb version to 1.0.39 inside the node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a known issue. I can see [here at this link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/180) people sharing the issue.

Following this guide will allow you to make sure your using the same tools everywhere. follow [this guide here.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/guides/genymotion.html)

> **Step 1: Use the same version of the Android tools everywhere**
>
> Genymotion and XDE/exp both bundle their own versions of the Android
> tools. In order for XDE or exp to communicate with Genymotion they
> need to share the same set of tools. You can do this by either telling
> XDE/exp to use Genymotion’s tools, or by installing Android Studio and
> telling both XDE/exp and Genymotion to use the tools from Android
> Studio.
>
> Choose one of these two options:
>
> Option 1: Use Genymotion’s tools Find Genymotion’s copy of adb. On
> macOS this is normally
> /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/.
>
> Add the Genymotion tools directory to your path.
>
> Make sure that you can run adb from your terminal.
>
> Option 2: Use Android Studio’s tools Install Android Studio.
>
> Make sure that you can run adb from your terminal.
>
> Open Genymotion and navigate to Settings -> ADB. Select “Use custom
> Android SDK tools” and update with your Android SDK directory: